# Proper capitalization for all character columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, dplyr

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm trying to capitalize every word in every column that is a character. I basically have a messy data set with names, addresses, and phone numbers, and I want to clean it so that the names and addresses are capitalized. Some names are totally lowercase, some all uppercase, some a mix.

This is what I've done (got the code for capitalizing from another question here), and I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
simpleCap <- function(x) { 
  s <- tolower(x) 
  s <- strsplit(s, " ")[[1]] 
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2), sep="", collapse=" ") 
} 

test <- test %>%
  mutate_if(function(.) is.character(.), sapply(., simpleCap))
```

The error I'm getting is:
"Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") :
object 'email@email.com' of mode 'function' was not found"

EDIT: Here's an example of my data set:

```
test <- data.frame("name" = c("Ellie Golding", "angela smith", "JOHN DOE", "jake elSON"), 
                 "address" = c("123 magic lane", "321 MAGIC LANE", "200 magIC LANE", "99 Magic Lane"),
                 "phone" = c(123, 122, 111, 132))
test <- test %>%
    mutate(name = as.character(name), address = as.character(address), phone = as.numeric(phone))
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `test %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), simpleCap))` or with `mutate_if` `test %>% mutate_if(is.character, simpleCap)` I guess there is no need for `sapply`

Comment: @akrun sorry which library is the across function part of?

Comment: it is from `dplyr` 1.0.0.  `mutate_if` should get deprecated.  it is better to show a small reproducible example.  I see that in your function, it is splitting the string and subsetting `[[1]]`.  May be it is inot needed

Comment: Weird, I have dplyr installed but it's not working for me. I also tried the mutate_if solution, but it makes all the rows contain the same data (it worked for the first row and duplicated that down for the rest of them).

Comment: because you are doing the `[[1]]` in `strsplit`.  For your function to work.  May be you need `rowwise` or `map`.  If your `packageVersion('dplyr')` is < 1.0.0, it won't work with `across` as it is introduced recently

Comment: I may write the function as `simpleCap <- function(x) {s <- str_remove(tolower(x), "\\s+.*"); paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2), sep="", collapse=" ") }`

Comment: Added some sample code - @IanCampbell, I did try toTitleCase actually, but I couldn't get it to work neatly across columns - i.e. it works if I manually type out which columns I want to change, but do you know how I can use it in a mutate_if type of thing to apply to all character columns only?

Comment: IanCampbell's solution works for me `test %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ tools::toTitleCase(tolower(.))))` or `test %>% mutate_if(is.character, ~ tools::toTitleCase(tolower(.)))`

Comment: Sorry how do I upgrade my dplyr version to get across?

Comment: @Kathy you can use the `mutate_if` as well as in the updated comment.  Regarding IanCampbell's comment, in `R >= 4.0`, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default in `data.frame` construction.  before that it was `TRUE`

Comment: Perfect, thank you both so much! Talk about timely answers - how can I give you guys upvotes?

Comment: @akrun can't have any more upvotes today since he's already hit the reputation cap, but if he answers with his custom function, you could unaccept my answer (which is fine with me) and accept his. Accepted answers are exempt.

Comment: @IanCampbell it's okay.  Your answer is more compact with toTitleCase.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `tools::toTitleCase` which is a base package:

```
library(dplyr) # Version >= 1.0.0
library(purrr)
test %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = which(map_lgl(.,~any(is.na(as.integer(as.character(.x)))))),
                ~ tools::toTitleCase(tolower(.))))
#           name        address phone
#1 Ellie Golding 123 Magic Lane   123
#2  Angela Smith 321 Magic Lane   122
#3      John Doe 200 Magic Lane   111
#4    Jake Elson  99 Magic Lane   132
```

Comment: @akrun This takes care of either character vectors or factors that don't convert to purely numeric.

Comment: One last thing - is there a way to ensure this capitalizes single-letter words? For example, if someone's name was A J, I'd wanted to keep it like that rather than a j

Comment: In that case, I'd probably go with akrun's `simpleCap` function from the comments on your question.